# μTorrent downloads remain stuck on the 'checked 0.0%' state

Tags: utorrent

This started happening randomly, all downloads stop right after getting their metadata with a "checked 0.0%" message. Closing and restarting the client *may* start the first download in the list, but that's also random.

One suggestion I found was to delete `%AppData%\utorrent\resume.dat`. The first time I fired up the client after I deleted it everything worked fine but then the file was recreated and I was back where I started.

I'm using the current stable version, 3.3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

a work around that seems to work for me is to stop all torrents, start them again then exit UTorrent - go to your AppData/Roaming folder under your user folder and delete all the .old files then restart UTorrent - all of my 6 downloads running now.

Hope this helps
:-)

Comment: Seems to work for me even after a reboot.

Answer (score 8):

I have added steps for both Mac OS X and Windows, works for all versions of uTorrent (including the latest versions). Please note: Windows is untested so if someone could confirm the steps I would be grateful.

**OS X**
1) Stop then Start all torrents
2) Exit uTorrent
3) Open **Terminal** and execute the following command (enter your password):
   `cd "~/Library/Application Support/uTorrent" && sudo rm -f *.old`

... This will delete all .old files.
4) Open uTorrent and you're good to go.

**Windows** *(untested)*
1) Stop then Start all torrents
2) Exit uTorrent
3) Open Windows Explorer and go to the following location:
`%AppData%/uTorrent`
4) Manually remove all files ending .old
5) Open uTorrent and you're good to go.

Comment: Jeffery's fix works. I did the same thing and it's functioning normally.

Comment: It did help for on my Mac OS. The only thing that was trouble some that it was adding one by one. So I have to repeat the procedure as many times as there were pending torrents. Nonetheless it helped. Thanks!

Comment: helped for me on macos.  didn't need "sudo" though.

Answer (score 3):

Upgrading to version 3.4 seems to solve the problem.

3.4 is (currently) alpha so it won't show up through the Help -> Check for Updates route, you'll have to install it manually. It's also not (very) quick to find on μtorrent's website, so here's a [quick link](http://www.utorrent.com/downloads/).

Comment: If there's a way to solve this without manually installing an alpha version I'll gladly give it the shiny green checkmark. This is quite easy for me, but not really easy for a couple of friends who aren't as tech savvy and/or don't feel comfortable relying on alpha versions.

Comment: I would simply wait until its released through the normal release channels.

Comment: @Ramhound Simply wait? That's not really an option, as when the problem appears (constantly for me), μtorrent doesn't download anything. Of course there are other torrent clients I could use, and that would also be a good enough solution to the problem, but I kinda like μtorrent.

Comment: If the Alpha release resolves this bug within the current version of μtorrent I can't think of another way for non-computer users to avoid being effected by this bug besides waiting on the next release of the software in question or using a different client that doesn't have the bug.

Comment: @Ramhound That's probably true, and I've posted a self answer exactly because I don't think there's a solution for the current stable version. That however doesn't mean I can't hope there is one ;)

Comment: Please check my solution. This even occurred on the latest (1.9.1)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, a sure solution is to update to version 3.4 (Alpha). I just did and it is working fine.

Here is the direct link to uTorrent's website for that : http://www.utorrent.com/downloads/

Another solution is to downgrade to a previous version. I know for certain that 3.3 (build 29333) works fine. But you'll have to search for that yourself (plus i'm not sure if there will be any problems with your current torrents when you downgrade)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, download the uTorrent Stable (3.3 build 29544) version.

Close the running (current) uTorrent, then install the downloaded one.

Answer (score 0):

What I get, using uTorrent 3.4 (build 30635), is a few ~30GB files keep having to be re-checked (for one reason, or another; looks like program crash, due 2 memory crash most probably) and this is taking AGES on an ok-system: 
Z68A-G43 (G3) - i7-3770 - Vengeance 2x4GB 2133MHz - GTX 650 Gainward - WD 1TB 64MB SATA - Win7 Pro/64 SP1 / Saucy Xfce AMD64

.. it's just a nightmare. :-/ Torrent(s) can NOT be stopped, during the check, and deleting .old files doesn't bypass the check. I have it not to auto-start downloads, so they can be launched one-at-a-time; but, it's ridiculous having to wait a few minutes every-so-often (and only one HDD, so the system is pretty much locked during that time)

(gonna look for a 64-bit Torrent client, perhaps, tnx)